# A baby working on a toilet

Tags: vocabulary

You have a baby on a toilet and he is giving his strength to do his work.
What words are appropriated to tell him and to describe him?

Asking:

1. Push hard
2. Flex
3. Give a strength

Describing:

1. you are forcing yourself to poop.
2. You are using a strength to ...

Which ones are correct and what other options are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General words of encouragement should be enough

> Push!
>   Push hard!
>   C'mon, you can do it!
>   The train is coming out of the tunnel

If they are very young, usually tone of voice and facial expressions are more important than actual words.

To describe what baby is doing

> He's pushing so hard to poop, his face is turning red.

These two could imply the red-face you are looking for

> He's poop is not cooperating.
>   He's struggling very hard to poop.

NOTE: If this is happening a lot (since you are looking for an exact expression), you may want to make sure baby has enough liquids or some sort of fruit juice to help.

Comment: Thank you peter. For the describing part, I am looking more at pushing attitude, with the reddish face. We could simply say like you, but is there  still an expression for his strength?

Comment: Ha Ha Ha "The train is coming out of the tunnel." At which point one should add the small precaution; "But not too hard to bring the tunnel along too!"